# Fitlering words

Tags: java

The elements of a String are names of towns, starting with capital letters. Fill in the elements of the string(not more than 50). Get the result for all the towns that contain the letter "e" 2, 3 or 4 times and don't contain the letter "p".

I can't figure out how to write a code that finds the words with at least two "e" and no "p" in it.

```
public class Проект4ж {
    static String[] towns = { "Еелена", "Асееновград", "Долно Калугерово", "Китеен", "Калофеер"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=0; i<towns.length; i++){
            if(towns[i].contains(!="p"){ 


                System.out.println(towns[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry the towns are in bulgarian, just the teachers asked us to do so.. Anyways you get the main point. I was thinking that I need to do the other part of loop with "charAt", but I'm not sure how.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place where you leave your homework for others to do.

Comment: public class Проект4ж {
static String[] towns = { "Еелена", "Асееновград", "Долно Калугерово", "Китеен", "Калофеер"};
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int е = 0;
     for (int i=0; i<towns.length; i++)
         if

Comment: Ok brother, ty. I'll try to do it myself, although I've been struggling for a day now.

Comment: I would recommend that you don't use non-ASCII characters in class names - this will cause you no end of problems if you compile on different platforms and don't take account of default encodings...

Comment: Put your existing code in the question, so we can see what you have and give some hints that will lead you in the right dircetion,

Comment: While noone is going to do your homework for you, you are most certainly allowed to ask specific questions about parts that you do not understand (but first look if someone already answered elsewhere). For your problem, try to separate the following (1) determine, whether a given word matches your criteria (2) filter words by matches

Comment: There's no issue with having homework questions. The problem is when people ask these questions and don't even show what they've tried, or where *specifically* they're stuck, or which part they *specifically* don't understand. If you demonstrate your effort in the post, people will help you out.

Comment: Some further ideas to improve your question: Change the title. Something like "Filtering words" or anything what describes the *actual* problem. Then remove all the boiler plate about your studies: Something like "I got stuck on my homework, this is what I have so far: " is more than enough. Nobody cares about if the exercise seemed to be simple... Finally: try to put code in your post that can be *compiled and run* and put a comment where you are stuck. Otherwise we first have to fix your program to then actually look into your problem. I hope you get the twist of how to ask a good question

Comment: `if(towns[i].contains(!="p")` This is not really the right way to express the condition. It would be more like `if(!towns[i].contains("p"))`

Comment: also, you might want to have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you adhere to these guidelines it is much more likely to 1. get upvotes 2. get useful answers..

Comment: Hint: how would you count the number of occurrences of a particular letter? Could you make a method to do that?

Comment: P.S. no one cares if your town names are in Bulgarian - it's your `class` name that worries me.

Comment: *Filtering not Fitlering ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right idea with `int e = 0` in your earlier comment.

```
for (int i=0; i<towns.length; i++){
    if(!towns[i].contains("p")){
        int e=0;
        for (int j=0; j<towns[i].length; j++){
            if(towns[i].charAt(j) == 'e' || towns[i].charAt(j) == 'E'){
                e++;
            }
        }
       if(e>1 && e<5){//This is assuming you don't want to print cities with more than 4 E's
           System.out.println(towns[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. I tried the way you showed, it doesn't work tho.When I use towns[i].length(if I remove [i], it just shows successful build without any result) it shows that it can't find symbol. Ty anyways and sorry for the inconvinience :)

Comment: @StockholmSyndrome hmm that's odd. Still, don't forget the possibility of capitol E and P also, such as your first town, "Еелена." It is still printed because 2 e's are counted, but other cases may not have the same circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the number of occurrence of a letter like this

```
 int count = StringUtils.countMatches( yourString, "e");
```

so check if it is 2 , 3 or 4 
and you have to do it for all your strings in your string Array
so you need a `Foreach`

```
  foreach (String s in towns)
                {
                     int count = StringUtils.countMatches( s, "e");
                      int countP = StringUtils.countMatches( s, "p");

                       if( (count == 2 || count == 3 || count == 4 ) && countP != 0  )
                         System.out.println(s);
                }
```

Comment: Using this method, perhaps `int count = StringUtils.countMatches( s, "e");` should be changed to `int count = StringUtils.countMatches( s.toLowerCase(), "e");` to accommodate the occasional capitol E. Also, the same thing when checking for `"p"`